# Show number of tables with special prefix inside a Database

Tags: mysql

How can i count tables which starts with special prefix in MYSQL database?

 I have below syntax below for showing table names which starts with prefix:

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'prefix\_%'
```

However i don't know how to count number of these tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think below SQL useful to you.Change your database name and prefix value.

```
SELECT count(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_type = 'base table' AND table_schema='database_name' AND table_name LIKE "prefix\_%";
```

Thank you.